# Using `bbmle:mle2` with vector parameters (already works using `optim`)

Tags: r, optimization, regression, mle

I am having some trouble using the `bbmle:mle2` function when trying to do regression. To illustrate my problem, I have come up with a toy example.

We define the minus log-likelihood for the Poisson distribution (or any custom distribution):

```
LL <- function(beta, z, x){
  -sum(stats::dpois(x, lambda = exp(z %*% beta), log = TRUE))
}
```

In the code above, `beta` is parameter vector I would like to estimate, `z` is a model/design matrix and `x` is my variable of interest.

I then generate some random data to work with:

```
set.seed(2)
age <- round(exp(rnorm(5000, mean = 2.37, sd = 0.78) - 1))
claim <- rpois(5000, lambda = 0.07
```

I can easily use `optim` for my regression. Here is the `intercept` only model:

```
z1 <- model.matrix(claim ~ 1)
optim(par = 0, fn = LL, z = z1, x = claim)
```

Here is the `intercept + age` model:

```
z2 <- model.matrix(claim ~ age)
optim(par = c(0, 0), fn = LL, z = z2, x = claim)
```

The way a large number of different models can be assessed is quite easy, one just has to specify the model matrix. How can this be made to work with the `mle2` function from the `bbmle` package?

I can do it, if `beta` is one-dimensional:

```
mle2(minuslogl = function(beta){ LL(beta = beta, z = z1, x = claim) },
  start = list(beta = 0))
```

But if `beta` is a vector, then I run into problems:

```
mle2(
  minuslogl = function(beta){ LL(beta = beta, z = z2, x = claim) },
  start = list(beta = c(0, 0)),
  vecpar = T,
  parnames = colnames(z2)
  )
```

I cannot get the syntax right and I cannot find any examples in the documentation or vignettes to help me. The problem is surely that `beta` is a vector now. The documentation suggests using the `vecpar = T` argument is the way forward for "compatibility with `optim`". Any tips would be appreciated.

Also, is there a way to pass the `z` and `x` arguments in my log-likelihood function in a more elegant way to `mle2` like I have done so in `optim`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the main problem is that you need to provide `start` as an atomic vector (not a list).

```
 library(bbmle)
 LL2 <- function(beta) {
     LL(beta, z = z2, x = claim)
 }
 parnames(LL2) <- colnames(z2)
 mle2(
   minuslogl = LL2 ,
     start = setNames(c(0,0),colnames(z2)),
     vecpar = TRUE
  )
```

It might help to know that you can implement something like Poisson regression much more easily in `bbmle` with the formula interface and the `parameters` argument:

```
mle2(claim~dpois(exp(loglambda)),     ## use log link/exp inverse-link
     data=data.frame(claim,age),      ## need to specify as data frame
     parameters=list(loglambda~age),  ## linear model for loglambda
     start=list(loglambda=0))         ## start values for *intercept*
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Ben! This is wonderful and solves my problem, so I should be able to implement it with my actual log-likelihood. Cheers!